# Can't figure out how to implement REGEX with AppleScript

Tags: regex, sed, applescript

I wrote a regex command to find and output the first instance of a line of digits in a string:

```
find:    ^[^\d]*(\d+).*
replace: $1
```

The problem is that in order to actually utilize this in AppleScript, the only way I know of doing this is with calling a shell script and using sed. I can't figure out how to actually use my regex in this way. I've tried for hours without any luck. This is as close as I can get, but it returns ALL the numbers in a string, rather than the first group of numbers:

```
set num to do shell script "sed 's/[^0-9]*//g' <<< " & quoted form of input
```

What I would really like is a way to use AppleScript to just WORK with regex and found match replacement ($1, $2, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `sed` does not support PCRE shorthand character classes like `\d`, nor does it support regex escapes inside bracket expressions.

Also, since you use POSIX BRE flavor of `sed` (no `-r` or `-E` option is used), to define a capturing group, you need `\(...\)`, not `(...)`.

Also, a `+` is matching a literal `+` symbol in POSIX BRE pattern, you need to escape it, but to play it safe, you can just expand `a+` to `aa*`.

Replacement backreference syntax in `sed` is `\` + number.

Use this POSIX BRE solution:

```
sed 's/^[^0-9]*\([0-9][0-9]*\).*/\1/'
```

or, if you use `-E` or `-r` option, a POSIX ERE solution:

```
sed -E 's/^[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*/\1/'
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[^0-9]*` - 0+ chars other than digits (also, you may use `[[:digit:]]*`)
- `\(` - start of a capturing group #1 (referred to with the `\1` placeholder from the replacement pattern) (in ERE, `(` will start a capturing group)
- `[0-9][0-9]*` = `[0-9]\+` (BRE) = `[0-9]+` (ERE) - 1+ digits
- `\)` - end of the capturing group (in POSIX ERE, `)`)
- `.*` - the rest of the line.

Comment: Can you break this expression down for me? Why is the found expression using [0-9] twice? I removed that extra [0-9] and it worked the same way...

Comment: @PatrickHennessey I explained that bit already, `a+` = `aa*`. `+` must be escaped in BRE POSIX pattern to denote a quantifier, but in some environments, `+` just does not work. I will add a POSIX ERE alternative.

Comment: This did the trick! While I'm here, is there a more concise way to achieve this using egrep? I feel like sed might not be the best command to use in order to get that "regex feel." I'd rather be able to use regex with PCRE.

Comment: @PatrickHennessey I think this is the best so far. `egrep` BSD version is good to use, but I do not know if you can use it. `grep -Eo '[0-9]+'`.

Comment: Is there a way to use grep to search a string input like we do with sed?

Comment: `grep` returns matches with `-o` option. `sed` removes or shows matches depending on options. GNU grep supports PCRE patterns: `grep -Po 'PCRE_pattern'`. Well, I do not know what you need exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Although you have your solution, I thought it might be useful to see another method of implementing regular expression matching and replacement using AppleScript (actually, AppleScript-ObjC):

```
    use framework "Foundation"
    use scripting additions
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    set regex to "(^[^\\d]*)(\\d+)(.*)"
    set input to "There are 250 billion stars in the galaxy, " & ¬
        "and 200 billion galaxies in the observable universe."

    re_match from the input against regex ¬
        given replacement:"$1two-hundred-and-fifty$3"
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    on re_match against pattern from str given replacement:fmt
        set regex to current application's NSRegularExpression's ¬
            regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern ¬
                options:(current application's ¬
                NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive) ¬
                |error|:(missing value)

        (regex's stringByReplacingMatchesInString:str ¬
            options:0 range:{0, length of str} ¬
            withTemplate:fmt) ¬
            as text
    end re_match
```

**Result:**

`"There are two-hundred-and-fifty billion stars in the galaxy, and 200 billion galaxies in the observable universe."`

Comment: That's disappointingly complicated. Isn't there a shell function that takes regex expressions directly and applies them to strings??

Comment: _Regular Expressions_ aren't the only form of pattern matching.  Bash has powerful, [built-in pattern matching](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern), which is similar in syntax to regular expressions.  So you can take a bash pattern and [directly apply those to strings](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#search_and_replace).

Comment: Another method is to employ an application's AppleScript functions.  For instance, the text editor [BBEdit](https://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/) is free, AppleScriptable and provides TONS of text manipulation functions that you can call from within your scripts, _including_ grep (regex) replacement, duplicate line matching, sorting, etc.