# how to show only the first 3 numbers in a string

Tags: applescript-objc

I use a shell command that returns me the following:
`Version-02520201604`
I would like to know how I could show the first 3 numbers separated by a dot.
ie `0.2.5`
I tried with SED and AWK but I couldn't.

Comment: Sounds like a Regex query could solve this. [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50865437/cant-figure-out-how-to-implement-regex-with-applescript).

Comment: Well, you could also just stick with AppleScript, for example `tell second word of "Version-02520201604" to set theResult to text 1 & "." & text 2 & "." & text 3`

Comment: @red_menace, thanks, Working perfectly!

Comment: @red_menace, I get the error: ```Can’t get word 2 of "".```if that ```02520201604``` doesn't exist could you tell me how to get around this?

Comment: An empty string wouldn't have word 2, so if that is the occasional result from your shell command, you can use a `try` statement to catch that error - for example set the version text to "unknown" or whatever.